# Why doesn't Tomcat show up when I grep netstat's output for 8080?

Tags: netstat, tomcat

I am doing the following to determine if Tomcat is running:

```
$ whoami
voops
voops@esavo00:~/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/bin#
$ ps -ef | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep
voops     8973     1  0 Apr22 ?        00:00:40 /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/voops/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/voops/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/endorsed -classpath /home/voops/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/voops/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/voops/apache-tomcat-7.0.57 -Dcatalina.home=/home/voops/apache-tomcat-7.0.57 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/voops/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

My reading of the above is that tomcat is running as a process owned by the currently logged-in user (voops). I then do a:

```
$ netstat -a | grep 8080
```

.. but nothing is grepped.

My `server.xml` file declares the following element:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

This is what `netstat -an | grep 8080` shows:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        1      0 131.176.161.23:44535        131.176.161.23:8080         CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 131.176.161.23:54600        131.176.161.23:8080         CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 131.176.161.23:51667        131.176.161.23:8080         CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 131.176.161.23:50348        131.176.161.23:8080         CLOSE_WAIT         
...  5 more lines similar to the one above
```

Comment: Maybe it's not listening on port `8080`? What does `netstat -tap | grep -i -e tomcat -e java`say?

Comment: @FloHimself it is listening on 8080 as I `tail -f` the `catalina.out` file and have seen: `INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]`

Comment: @FloHimself Also the `server.xml` file declares a `Connector` for HTTP/1.1 on port 8080.

Comment: try `netstat -an` to get numeric result, otherwise try `netstat -a|grep http-alt`

Comment: @Lambert updated the question with `netstat -an` output. I see something listening to 8080 (if I read the output correctly) but how do I know that's Tomcat?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus what does netstat show when adding the `-p` flag? This should show PID and name of the process listening on `8080`

Comment: Yeah, that nails it: `netstat -anp | grep 8080`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case the comments to the question were not clear enough, I am adding an answer here, along with a few Pointers not mentioned in those comments.

"Why doesn't Tomcat doesn't show up when I grep netstat's output for 8080 ?"
Short Answer :
Because Port Number 8080 is getting converted to string http_alt, which will not match the grep pattern.

Details :
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers , we can see that Port 8080 is Officially **"HTTP alternate (http_alt)—commonly used for Web proxy and caching server, or for running a Web server as a non-root user"**.
Basically, `netstat` will show "http-alt" for Port 8080 with Default Display.

When using `netstat -n`, the Port numbers (like 8080 for http-alt) will be shown, & you will be able to grep it. Process ID of the listening Process will be shown when running netstat with -p.

So use `netstat -pa | grep http-alt` or `netstat -pan | grep :8080` to see the tomcat Entry.

Alternately, use `lsof -P | grep :8080` which will also show the Process ID & Process Name owning the socket which is listening on Port 8080.
Here -P will prevent Port Numbers getting converted to strings (like 8080 for http-alt)

Another alternative is `nmap $SERVER` or `namp localhost`, which will show all open ports including 8080, when tomcat is running fine.